# Have ssh try a LAN IP before the internet address

Tags: server, ssh

I have a home server connected to my local LAN and the internet. 
Say its LAN IP is

```
192.169.0.10
```

and it has an internet address of

`awesomeserver.no-ip.org` (DNS alias).

I access it regularly from a laptop over `ssh`. I want to configure my laptop so that it first **tries the LAN IP** for more speed, if that doesn't work it should **fall back to the internet address**. How is this possible? It should work with nautilus' sftp connections as well as terminal `ssh` commands.

Answer (score 0):

Use the DNS name. When routing traffic from the LAN, the router will resolve the name awesomeserver.no-ip.org and discover that it is equal to its own Internet-facing IP address. Then it will look through its list of "virtual server" addresses (or whatever NAT is called on the router) and forward the traffic to 192.168.0.10. The traffic from your laptop will not get outside your LAN.

Comment: Thanks, the 169 was just a type. I used 168 from the start, of course.